# Modifying/Customizing the design of a wordpress gutenberg block

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-gutenberg, gutenberg-blocks

for a website I want to add a gutenberg block listing the latest posts of a certain category. The "latest-post" block by wordpress is capable of doing this, but I would like to customize the design of that listing. Is it possible to customize wordpress-own blocks for some themes?

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

yes you can customize a block for a specific page or a particular category.

In the relevant page, look at the css classes in the  and then you apply a style to your block

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But is there a way to change the whole structure of the block's output (for example adding another div-block)?